# Would it be illegal to make a exact replica of a browser game for Android?

Tags: copyright

I found this browser game that I really like and that I think could easily be ported to Android.

Would it be illegal/could I get in trouble for taking this browser game and making an exact replica of it for Android that would use the same image and sound assets.

Comment: If it is a browser based game, then the creator must still be around, or at least someone is running the server it is located on. Maybe contact them, convert to android, split any money. Be sweet if game was written in java, maybe get source, be easy peezy.

Answer (score 2):

See [Can I legally update, republish and sell an old electronic game?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/can-i-legally-update-republish-and-sell-an-old-electronic-game)

The point of that question - the fact that the game is not on the market anymore - is not relevant to you, but the basics of trademarks are still relevant.

You can't legally copy the game - the images, artwork, sounds and/or the overall design - and turn it into your game. That's called infringement, and the maker of the browser game could pursue you in civil court.

You could copy parts of the game into a new game, but in that case, Fair Use comes into play, and you need to carefully consider that concept and your usage:  [In the US, when is fair use a defense to copyright infringement?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/in-the-us-when-is-fair-use-a-defense-to-copyright-infringement)

Why not contact the author of the browser game and ask if you can adapt an Android version?